# Rigidbody and collider are not working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a snake with the mechanics of "gravity of the planet". When I add a "survivor" he falls into the planet.
-Сolliders enabled
-CollisionDetection in the screenshot

public class SurvivorMovement

```
public override void MoveToTarget(Rigidbody target)
{
Vector3 direction = target.position- transform.position;
_rigidbody.MovePosition(_rigidbody.position + _multiplier * _speedMovement * Time.deltaTime * direction);
_rigidbody.velocity= Vector3.zero; //prohibit overclocking
}
```

public class ControllerSurvivorMovement

```
public void Move()
{
for (int i = 1; i < _survivorMovements.Count; i++)
{
Rigidbody preveuPosition = _survivorMovements[i - 1].Rigidbody;
_survivorMovements[i].MoveToTarget(preveuPosition);
}
}
```

public class ArtificialGravityAttractor

```
public void Attract(Rigidbody bodyAttracted, Transform body)
{
Vector3 normalizePositionBody = NormalizePositionBodyOnAttractor(body);

Vector3 forceGravity = normalizePositionBody * _powerGravity;

bodyAttracted.AddForce(forceGravity);

Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(body.up, normalizePositionBody) * body.rotation;
bodyAttracted.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(body.rotation, targetRotation, _speedRotation * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMedN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNcw0.jpg)

I tried changing Rigidbody to Transform, changing the anchor, reducing the force of gravity.